# Rounding Error: Harmonic mean with exponent of small numbers

Tags: rounding, mean, exponential

Let us say I have log_a1=-1000, log_a2=-1001, and  log_a3=-1002. 
n=3

I want to get the harmonic mean (HM) of a1, a2 and a3 (not log_a1, log_a2 and log_a3) such that HM = n/[1/exp(log_a1) + 1/exp(log_a2) + 1/exp(log_a3)].

However, due to rounding error exp(log_a1)=exp(-1000)=0 and accordingly 1/exp(log_a)=inf and HM=0.

Is there any mathematical trick to do?  It is okay to get either HM or log(HM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is probably to keep things in log scale. Many scientific languages have a *log-add-exp* function (e.g. [`numpy.logaddexp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logaddexp.html) in python) that does what you want to high precision, with both the input and the result in log form.

The idea is that you want to compute `e^-1000 + e^-1001 + e^-1002`, so you factor it to `e^-1000 (1 +  + e^-1 + e^-2)` and take the log. The result is `-1000 + log(1 + e^-1 + e^-2)`, which can be computed without loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

log(HM)=log(n)-log(1)+log_a_max - log(sum(1./exp(log_ai - log_a_max)))

For a=[-1000, -1001, -1002];

log(HM)=-1001.309